IPC node for Solana
For ethereum, we can make IPC calls, if the RPC and client are running on the same machine (eg. in Python, can use https://pypi.org/project/ethereum-ipc-client/).
Is there some way to configure a solana RPC node to cater to IPC requests from the same machine?

Solana nodes only respond to JSON-RPC and admin RPC calls, there's no generic "IPC socket" available as with Ethereum nodes.
You can configure a Solana node to bind its RPC service to a local address, and then it will service RPC requests only locally.
But I'm not sure if this answers your question, because it's not clear what you aim to do with an IPC client.
